# How to change the app icon background color in react-native for android

Tags: react-native, appicon

Please how do I properly change the default background color of app icon which is white to a one of my choice?

I'm using React-native 0.62

Answer (score 1):

if your icon has already a white background you are not able to change that from the app,if you want to do that it need some complicated border detecting and then you can change it!, you need to modify changes outside of app, or just make its background transparent with Photoshop then use and give background to its parent.
i hope it helps

Comment: I think the problem is not with the icon I choose but the result because whether the chosen icon is transparent or not, I still have that icon surrounded by a white background. Whereas other icons from other apps have colored backgrounds.

Comment: so thats is because the bg of your parent is white, if your image has a transparent bg , you can use give to that image the backgroundColor style,

Comment: I didn't get you well. Here I'm talking about the icon app. So please where I can update that backgroundColor style?

Comment: did you try putting a background with photoshop or similar app then test it? because react native does not have control on that things! just change the background with photoshop and use it.